# win32com Python: Connecting to one of multiple mailboxes

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I have 2 mailboxes (abc@er.com and def@er.com) in outlook and need to connect to a specific mailbox. By default, Python's win32com.client is connecting to the wrong one.

Is there a parameter to specify which mailbox to connect to? My code is:

`outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items`

I have tried very hard to find which parameters allow me to connect to a specific mailbox but did not see anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you see what `for folder in outlook.Folders: print(folder.Name)` gives you?

Comment: Thanks! It works. For some reason I was assuming that "folders" would be for folders like Inbox, Sent, etc and that there would be something like outlook.Mailbox for mailboxes. Did not know that they are all considered folders.

Comment: Glad it works for you! I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to enumerate the mailboxes with:

```
for folder in outlook.Folders: 
    print(folder.Name)
```